# How do I call the Google AI Platform API with a TensorFlow image classification model

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I just uploaded my saved_model.pb to Google AI Platform and it is an image classification model. When I test the model in the command line, it works fine. But if I try to call the API, I keep getting an error: "Request payload size exceeds the limit"

I'm sure that passing a small image can't be using too much space.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216095/using-gcloud-ml-serving-for-large-images

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple mistake. For anyone else that faces this: I had lots of spaces in my JSON, and once I removed them, it worked!